# What is the repetition distribution of Pulling balls out of a bag?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, hypergeometric-distribution

I have m balls in a bag, n of them are blue.
The target is to pull out k blue balls.
(m>n>k)
Once I pull out a ball I don't put it back.
I want find out the distribution of the number of times I need to pull a ball out of the bag ( as a function of m,n,k ).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_hypergeometric_distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Negative hypergeometric distribution.
If x is the number of times I need to pull a ball out of the bag the distribution of x-k will be:
\begin{equation}
NHG_{m,m-n,k}(x-k)
\end{equation}

The pmf for x is:
\begin{equation}
\frac{ {{x-1}\choose{x-k}} \times {{m-x}\choose{m-n-x+k}}}{{{m}\choose{m-n}}}
\end{equation}

The expected value of x is:
\begin{equation}
k \times \frac{m+1}{n+1}
\end{equation}

Thanks to Glen_b for the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_hypergeometric_distribution).