# What is the repetition distribution of Pulling balls out of two bags?

Tags: probability, distributions, hypergeometric-distribution

I have two bags each with $m$ balls.

In the first bag I have $n_1$ blue balls.

In the second bag I have $n_2$ blue balls.

The target is to pull out a total of k blue balls from both bags ($m>n_1>n_2>k$).

I pull out one ball from the first bag and then one ball from the second bag, and so on. Once I pull out a ball I don't put it back.

All the balls have numbers on them, 1..m in each bag. If I pull two blue balls with the same number it counts only once for the k total blue balls I have to pull.

I want to find out the distribution of the number of times I need to pull a ball ( as a function of m,n,k ).

I have a solution for the case of one bag [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/295074/what-is-the-repetition-distribution-of-pulling-balls-out-of-a-bag).

Comment: Do you mean you continue until you have both pulled at least $k$ blue balls from the first bag and at least $k$ blue balls from the second bag? Or you continue until you have pulled a total of $k$ blue balls (between both bags)?

Comment: total of $k$ blue balls (between both bags)

Comment: Also, could you give some context for what motivated this question? If this a homework problem, can you explain what you have tried so far?

Comment: It is not a homework. It is something I am doing for my research. The real problem is much more complicated. I made it simpler to isolate just the thing that I am currently stuck on. I am not sure it has a simple answer. However, I hope someone here could help me solve it ,or give me an idea how to progress from here.

Comment: Ok, so the balls in each bag are labeled 1.. $m$, but which of these labels are on blue balls? Is it just 1..$n_1$ for the first bag and 1..$n_2$ for the second? If $A_1 \subseteq \{1..m\}$ is the set of labels on blue balls in the first bag and $A_2 \subseteq \{1..m\}$ is the set of labels on blue balls in the second bag, then we know $|A_1| = n_1$ and $|A_2| = n_2$, but it seems we would need to know $|A_1 \cap A_2|$ in order to determine the distribution. Or do you want this to be introduced as an additional parameter?

Comment: We can't know which labels the blue balls have. It can be in the first bag: (1-white) (2-blue) (3-white) (4-white) (5-blue) and in the second bag (1-blue) (2-white) (3-blue) (4-white) (5-blue).

Comment: |A1∩A2||A1∩A2| is unknown, it may be a parameter, that has it's own distribution...

Comment: So if $A_1$ and $A_2$ are random, are you wanting to assume that they are random samples without replacement from $\{1, \dots, m\}$ (with size $n_1$ and $n_2$ respectively), with $A_1$ and $A_2$ being independent of one another? Or are you wanting a solution conditioned on $|A_1 \cap A_2|$?

Comment: $A_1$ and $A_2$ are independent.

Comment: @Brent Your questions about the labels appear to be irrelevant.

Comment: It seems relevant in light of the condition (added in an edit by the OP): "All the balls have numbers on them, 1..m in each bag. If I pull two blue balls with the same number it counts only once for the k total blue balls I have to pull." For instance the expected number of required draws would be lower if the labels on the blue balls were disjoint between the two bags than if the labels overlapped.

Comment: @Brent Thank you for pointing out that edit: it represents a significant (and confusing) modification of the question.  In light of that change, my answer no longer applies.

Comment: @whuber, I thought your answer was also interesting and could be useful for comparison (to see how the new condition in the edit affects the results), especially since I referenced your plots in my answer. Might you consider undeleting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved by considering a time-inhomogeneous Markov chain. Let $t$ represent the time at which $t$ balls have been drawn, and define

\begin{align*}
X_t &= \text{number of distinct labels of blue balls drawn so far (i.e. by time $t$)}\\
Y_t &= \text{number of blue balls in first bag with labels not already drawn}\\
Z_t &= \text{number of blue balls in second bag with labels not already drawn}\\
\end{align*}
The initial state is $(X_0, Y_0, Z_0) = (0, n_1, n_2)$. We need to consider the transition probabilities at time $t$.

For even $t$, say $t=2s$, the next draw will be from the first bag. At this time, the first bag has $Y_t$ blue balls and $m-s$ total balls, so with probability $Y_t/(m-s)$ a blue ball will be drawn with a label not previously drawn. In this case, under the random labeling assumption, with probability $Z_t/(m-X_t)$ the label will match one of the blue balls in the second bag. So we can describe the transition probabilities for even $t$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
&P((X_{t+1}, Y_{t+1}, Z_{t+1}) = (x, y, z) \ |\ (X_{t}, Y_{t}, Z_{t}) = (x, y, z)) \\
&\quad= 1-\frac{Y_{t}}{m-s}\\ \\
&P((X_{t+1}, Y_{t+1}, Z_{t+1}) = (x+1, y-1, z) \ |\ (X_{t}, Y_{t}, Z_{t}) = (x, y, z)) \\
&\quad= \frac{Y_{t}}{m-s}\left(1-\frac{Z_{t}}{m-X_{t}}\right)\\ \\
&P((X_{t+1}, Y_{t+1}, Z_{t+1}) = (x+1, y-1, z-1) \ |\ (X_{t}, Y_{t}, Z_{t}) = (x, y, z)) \\
&\quad= \frac{Y_{t}}{m-s}\frac{Z_{t}}{m-X_{t}}
\end{align*}
For odd $t$, say $t=2s-1$, the next draw will be from the second bag, and we similarly have
\begin{align*}
&P((X_{t+1}, Y_{t+1}, Z_{t+1}) = (x, y, z) \ |\ (X_{t}, Y_{t}, Z_{t}) = (x, y, z)) \\
&\quad = 1-\frac{Z_{t}}{m-s}\\ \\
&P((X_{t+1}, Y_{t+1}, Z_{t+1}) = (x+1, y, z-1) \ |\ (X_{t}, Y_{t}, Z_{t}) = (x, y, z)) \\
&\quad = \frac{Z_{t}}{m-s}\left(1-\frac{Y_{t}}{m-X_{t}}\right)\\ \\
&P((X_{t+1}, Y_{t+1}, Z_{t+1}) = (x+1, y-1, z-1) \ |\ (X_{t}, Y_{t}, Z_{t}) = (x, y, z)) \\
&\quad = \frac{Z_{t}}{m-s}\frac{Y_{t}}{m-X_{t}}
\end{align*}
In this way, beginning with $t=0$ the pmf of $(X_{t+1}, Y_{t+1}, Z_{t+1})$ can be computed in terms of the pmf of $(X_t, Y_t, Z_t)$. Summing up over all possible values of $Y_t$ and $Z_t$, we obtain the (marginal) pmf of $X_t$. If we let $J$ denote the required number of draws, then $P(J \leq t) = P(X_t \geq k)$, so we may find the pmf of $J$ using the pmf of $X_t$. Here is some (not particularly efficient) R code for carrying this out:

```
prob = function(m, n1, n2){
  p = array(0, dim = c(2*m+1, n1+n2+1, n1+1, n2+1))
  p[1, 1, n1+1, n2+1] = 1
  for(i in 0:(2*m-1)){
    for(x in 0:(n1+n2)){
      for(y in 0:n1){
        for(z in 0:n2){
          if(i%%2 == 0){
            s = i/2
            q = p[i+1, x+1, y+1, z+1]
            if(q>0){
              p[i+2, x+1, y+1, z+1] = p[i+2, x+1, y+1, z+1] + q * (1 - y/(m-s))
              if(y>0){
                p[i+2, x+2, y, z+1] = p[i+2, x+2, y, z+1] + q * y/(m-s) * (1 - z/(m-x))
                p[i+2, x+2, y, z] = p[i+2, x+2, y, z] + q * y/(m-s) * z/(m-x)
              }
            }
          }else{
            s = (i-1)/2
            q = p[i+1, x+1, y+1, z+1]
            if(q>0){
              p[i+2, x+1, y+1, z+1] = p[i+2, x+1, y+1, z+1] + q * (1 - z/(m-s))
              if(z>0){
                p[i+2, x+2, y+1, z] = p[i+2, x+2, y+1, z] + q * z/(m-s) * (1 - y/(m-x))
                p[i+2, x+2, y, z] = p[i+2, x+2, y, z] + q * z/(m-s) * y/(m-x)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } 
  p
}

pmf_J = function(m, n1, n2, k){
  p = prob(m, n1, n2)
  cdf = numeric(2*m+1)
  for(i in 0:(2*m)){
    cdf[i+1] = sum(p[i+1, k:(n1+n2)+1,,])
  }
  diff(cdf)
}
```

And here are some example plots, using the same parameter combinations as in whuber's answer:

```
params = expand.grid(k = c(4, 12, 20), n1 = c(12, 19, 23), m = 50)
params$n2 = 24 - params$n1
png("charts.png", width=750, height=750)
par(mfrow = c(3,3), cex = 0.9)
for(i in 1:nrow(params)){
  pa = params[i,]
  pmf = pmf_J(pa$m, pa$n1, pa$n2, pa$k)
  print(sum(pmf))
  plot(1:(2*pa$m), pmf,
       xlab = "j",
       ylab = "Probability",
       main = paste0("m=",pa$m,", n1=",pa$n1,", n2=",pa$n2,", k=",pa$k)) 
}
dev.off()
```

[image]

For parameter choices where at least one of $n_1$, $n_2$, or $k$ is small compared to $m$, there is little impact from the condition that a blue ball with a repeated label does not count, and so the plots agree fairly closely in these cases. The starkest difference can be seen in the upper-right chart ($n_1= n_2 = 12$, $k=20$). Here $k$ exceeds $\max\{n_1, n_2\}$ (contrary to the assumption in the question), which means that there is positive probability that all balls in both bags will be exhausted without $k$ distinctly labeled blue balls being drawn; in this case, we could set $J = \infty$, but the chart only shows the probabilities for finite $J$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. I am trying to understand the code you wrote. Why did you write p in the prob function just before the end of the function?

Comment: That is R's way of returning a value from a function. You can also write `return(p)`, but the `return` keyword is optional when it's the last expression in a function.